# AngularJS dropdown select input with predetermined or custom input options

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown `md-select` input box filled with a few pre-determined options, but I also would like the user to be able to type in their own options.

I'm close here in this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HI1DbblEp2XAylBJfq3K?p=preview), but I can't quite get it to work right. I'm having two issues:

1. When the user selects the "other..." option, the dropdown collapses before they have time to enter anything.
2. Even if I sneak in an entry before the dropdown closes, I can't get my value to persist and show up.

The HTML:

```
<div layout="row">
    <md-select ng-model="ctrl.userCountry">
      <md-option>
        <em>None</em>
      </md-option>
      <md-option value="india">india</md-option>
      <md-option value="china">bangladesh</md-option>
      <md-option ng-blur="ctrl.customEntry({{customText}})">
        <input placeholder="other..." ng-model="customText" type="text">
      </md-option>
      </md-select>
  </div>
```

The js file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

  this.userCountry = 'india';

  this.customEntry = function(input) {
   userCountry = input; 
  };

});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/smBhh3ecEBVdojRZAg6b?p=preview), where `input` is already focused, when `md-select` have expanded, so user can select plain `md-option`, just clicking on it, as always do, or immediately start to type *#other* option into `input`, then he will click on it or outside, at both cases, value will be assigned to  `userCountry`:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
  <div layout="row">
    <md-select ng-model="ctrl.userCountry" ng-click='ctrl.focus()'>
      <md-option>
        <em>None</em>
      </md-option>
      <md-option value="india">india</md-option>
      <md-option value="china">bangladesh</md-option>
      <md-option ng-click='ctrl.optionClick(temp)'>
        <input id='other' placeholder="other..." type="text" ng-model='temp' ng-change='ctrl.customEntry(temp)'>
      </md-option>
      </md-select>
  </div>

  <div layout="row">
    return value: {{ctrl.userCountry}}
  </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  self = this;
  this.userCountry = 'india';

  this.customEntry = function(input) {
   this.userCountry = input; 
  };

  this.optionClick = function(input) {
    $timeout(function(){
      self.userCountry = input; 
    }, 100);
  };

  this.focus = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("other").focus();
    }, 100);
  }

});
```